# Is it possible to simulate Amazon cloud search and dynamoDB for developement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm looking to build an application off Amazon cloud search and dynamo DB and I don't want to waste money or free tier during application development. So, I'm wondering if Amazon Dynamo DB and cloud search can somehow be simulated on your local machine during the development period? If not, what is the best alternative to create a stub? I'm considering Apache Cassandra and Solr. Any other alternatives for low cost development?

Also, I'm developing on Windows so, I'd like to know if there is a good windows alternative to Cassandra, that'll save me the complexity of running Cassandra over a VM. An open source database that could be embedded in Java would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [ddbmock](http://ddbmock.readthedocs.org/), which is a Python library, with quite a lot of success. It has support for most of the features of a live DynamoDB instance, and even supports some of the error messages (although the messages might not match 100%).

There are some others out there too: [Alternator](https://github.com/mboudreau/Alternator/) written in Java, and [clientside_aws](https://github.com/perrystreetsoftware/clientside_aws) written in Ruby.

Comment: I checked out alternator, though I'm wondering if it is a persistent database or just a simulation that will start an empty database every time its loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python package that can simulate AWS CloudSearch locally using MongoDB: https://github.com/oisinmulvihill/nozama-cloudsearch

Answer (score 2):

Try [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.html). It's a simulator of DynamoDB. I've made a Maven plugin for it: [jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score -4):

I really appreciate the way you think, there is no way where you can actually simulate the cloud search and dynamo db environment. Those stuffs belongs to AWS, you can just use the API's or SDK if available. I feel AWS uses solr at the back end for cloud search I am not sure about the dynamo DB, I feel its a custom Engine.

Windows alternative to Casaandra?? I am really not sure about that. I always prefer Linux or Ubuntu to be very specific when it comes development.